# autorelease pool causes crash in RubyCocoa application

Tags: cocoa, debugging, autorelease, ruby-cocoa

I'm having crash in my application, which says

trying to pop an unknown autorelease pool:
10/19/09 11:40:11 AM MyApp[89480] *** attempt to pop an unknown
autorelease pool (0x11bc800)

How to trace it down?

Since it's RubyCocoa application it's almost impossible to trace it with gdb in Xcode environment. So mostly it's about logging. There is an irb debugger, which gives same results as logging.

Thanks,

Nava

Comment: Assuming total strangers have any idea what your code does or looks like would be #1 in my book.

Comment: @NSD This question was originally posted on Oct 20 with a concrete example and question. Too pity you didn't see it before I edited the post. Anyway the question is how do i trace it? And being patient to others will result that others will be patient to you... (this about downvoting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.corbinstreehouse.com/blog/2007/10/instruments-on-leopard-how-to-debug-those-random-crashes-in-your-cocoa-app/comment-page-1/#comment-43762

And from the same author - put a break in CFLog.

The link is really helpful!